# How to get click and install in user acquisition part in flurry?

Tags: android, flurry, flurry-analytics

I am following these steps

1. I have created campaign in user acquisition part and create a campaign url
2. I have put the campaign url in playstore url (ie. playstoreurl&campaignurl)
3. I have put this url in my website ad.

I am getting many click on website ad but flurry is not showing any click.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make any changes to the tracking link generated by UAA(skip step 2 above). It should automatically redirect the user to the app store.

Here are a couple of videos that explain how to use UAA:

https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/lexicon/videos/#user-acquisition-analytics-getting-started

https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/lexicon/videos/#user-acquisition-analytics-reporting

If you continue having a problem please email support@flurry.com

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have resolved it. My problem was ad url which I have choose wrong.